# Can I use a thru axle with a longer pitch when the manufacturer specifies a smaller one?

Tags: compatibility, through-axle

I bought a frame which didn't had the axle (lynskey cooper cx). The one which lynskey sells is 142x12x1pitch.

I'm from europe and I can't find any axle with the same specs, furthermore a lot of websites don't even mention this third measure, is it possible to use an axle with 1.5, 1.6 or 1.75 pitch instead?

**Edit**: Thanks to Argenti's answer I've seen that I understood wrong the terms. But I'm still having difficulties. The answer of the manufacturer is the following:
12x142 Axle Specifications:

```
12x142x1.0TP

12mm Diameter
142mm Hub Spacing
1.0 Thread Pitch
Overall Length of 166mm +/- 2mm
```

Using the link that Argenti provided, I can't see many options which fulfill this requirements, those would be:

```
 Kcnc   Indexing – Syntace X12  Tapered     167mm   12×1    19mm
 Rear “Scott” Standard 12×142
```

But still all of them have different total thread length

Comment: the 1mm pitch seems to be the syntace X12 standard as far as i see from @argenti-appearatus 's link. you can get that from various retailers in europe with the search term "syntace x12" - that is, the one from syntace, i think there are other manufacturers but i didn't see them on any shop.

Comment: @pseyfert I've updated the question with some more information

Answer (score 1):

I think you are perhaps confusing the thread pitch with the length of the threaded section of the axle - as your title says 'axle with a longer pitch'. The pitch is the distance between threads in mm.

You definitely cannot use a through axle with a different thread pitch than your frame, it would not screw into the threaded right hand dropout.

To figure out a compatible through axle, you need to know:

- Total length - which depends on the hub width and thickness of dropouts
- Length of threaded section - the match the right dropout
- Pitch

You already know the pitch1, hub width is 142mm, dropouts can be measured. Armed with that info you should be able to find a matching axle.

Here's a resource I find helpful: http://blog.fairwheelbikes.com/reviews-and-testing/high-end-skewer-review/all-about-thru-axles/

Comment: Thank you, you are right, I was confusing terms. I've contacted the manufacturer, and they say that that it is 142x12 1pitch and total length 166mm but in the link you have provided it does't look like there is such an option.

Comment: @nck I doubt that web page is comprehensive.

Comment: i know DT Swiss makes one that is 142x12 , 1 pitch, total length 167.7mm - HWQASM00S2961S - No idea if that would work or not though

Comment: @NateW thanks a lot I found that one in stock. It was shown as "DT Swiss X-12 HR RWS Thru Axle 12x142" Hopefully I do not have to return it. It's a nightmare so many different things...